# Worksheet Range Reference Not Needed?

Tags: excel, vba

The below appears multiple times throughout the script.  Is there a reason the the Worksheets(2).UsedRange is used by itself?  Would there be a reason to have to keep this here? It looks redundant to me.

```
Sub Active_Check()

Worksheets(2).Activate

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets(2).UsedRange ' Why is this here?
Worksheets(2).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<=" & Date - 7
```

Comment: calling `.UsedRange` by itself is sometimes used to force the sheet to recalculate the used range. I don't think its a very reliable way to go about that though

Comment: I have never heard that before.  And if that was the case wouldnt they have to redefine the range?

Comment: you are making the world a better place by removing all the `.Activate`s and `.Select`s. Good on you!

Comment: @archerBird They kill my soul

Comment: UsedRange is sensitive to "non-content" things like cell formatting (fill etc) so it's a pretty unreliable way of setting a range to filter - better to use something like `Range("A1").CurrentRegion` (assuming your data contains no bank rows or columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this call to `.UsedRange` is an attempt to reset the used range of the sheet. I've seen this suggested around the internet ([example](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/6630-reset-the-used-range/)), though I haven't found it to be a very effective nor consistent way to reset the UsedRange. But, to answer your question, I believe this is what the original author was trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  I will just redefine another way.  I have never seen this before and I am in agreement with everyone else on this thread that this doesn't seem consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this explanation helps:

```
Sub Active_Check()

    'select the sheet 2
    Worksheets(2).Activate

    'calculates the last row on sheet 2
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'this is usually used to assign to ranges/arrays. Not needed here.
    Worksheets(2).UsedRange ' Why is this here?

    'everything done before this point is useless because is not used in here.
    'This is filtering on sheet 2 all the data by the column 12 with criteria lesser or equal than
    'Date variable minus seven.
    Worksheets(2).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<=" & Date - 7
```